# How make default value validation?

Tags: zend-framework, validation

I have created an input(text) element which has a default value 'Email'. Label to field was deleted.

How to validate the text field to see if it contains the default value?

Thnx!

Comment: Can you show some code, it's quite hard to understand your question!

Comment: Опиши проблему на русском языке, я переведу и обновлю твой вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Identical validator, passing your default value as the string to compare against.